# how can I make this work without cin.get()

Tags: c++

How can I change this so it works without cin.get?

```
void convert(int bit[],string &s)
{    
    char c = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        c = c+(bit[i] << i);
    }
    cin.get();
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `cin.get()` in there at all?

Comment: Please define "works". As you are not using the result of `cin.get()` you should be able to simply delete that line.

Comment: because withut it, cout will not show c

Comment: What does the `cin.get()` statement do for you? Are you waiting for the user to press a key?

Comment: Add an end of line to your string, maybe?

Comment: I already tried without cin.get, and It does not show c

Comment: You probably want to flush it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're even trying to do.  You throw
away the return value of `cin.get()`, so it's only effect is to
extract a character from the input stream, and execute any side
effects associated with extracting a character.  (`std::cout` is
tied to `std::cin` by default, so one of the side effects would
be to flush `std::cin`.)  If you want the flush, you can do it 
directly, e.g. `std::cout.flush()`, or simply `std::cout << c <<
flush`.  Note, however that outputting a character may not do
what you want.  If you want to output the actual value of `c`,
rather than interpreting it as an encoded character, you'll have
to convert it to an integral type larger then `char` first.  And
of course, if plain char is signed, you may want to convert it
to an `unsigned char` first, unless you're prepared to deal with
negative values.